# VS 2022 can not load designer for .Net 5 and Higher winforms projects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

My Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.5 (the latest version) can not load Winforms within WinFormsApp projects.
Everything is OK within .NET Framework Winforms project, but not with the Core frameworks such as .NEt5, .Net6 and .Net7.

It will stuck at Loading Designer... and will give these errors in the output window:

```
[12:27:38.057108] fail: [WinFormsApp145]: Invalid value for dpi: 0

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[12:29:35.944976] fail: [WinFormsApp145]: Timed out while connecting to named pipe: DesignToolsServer.b87b8818-7740-468a-bbff-0844b600f8a3

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[12:29:35.958968] fail: Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.ServerException: Timed out while connecting to named pipe.
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.<ConnectToStreamAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.<LaunchAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.<CreateHostAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<CreateClientAsync>d__29.MoveNext()

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[12:29:36.215821] warn: Cannot update selection in server process as Session is not connected.
```

also I enabled the verbose log messages and here is the result:

```
[11:24:10.840322] info: Creating VsDesignerLoader
[11:24:11.224447] info: [Thread 1] Creating design-time ITypeResolutionService.
[11:24:11.380279] trce: Current VS Version = 17.0
[11:24:11.385277] info: Start processing enqueued assemblies
[11:24:11.385277] trce: Loaded Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Protocol in 00:00:00.0000140 [thread 30]
[11:24:11.389273] trce: Processed 'Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Protocol' in 00:00:00.0042090
[11:24:11.393271] info: Added 'Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Protocol'
[11:24:11.394271] trce: Loaded Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client in 00:00:00.0000122 [thread 30]
[11:24:11.429252] trce: Processed 'Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client' in 00:00:00.0352671
[11:24:11.431250] info: Added 'Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client'
[11:24:11.683106] info: Visual Studio culture: en-US (0x0409)
[11:24:11.683106] info: [Thread 30] Launching server...
[11:24:11.701095] info: Is processor architecture ARM64: False
[11:24:12.607580] info: Added 'mscorlib'
[11:24:12.607580] trce: Loaded System.Windows.Forms in 00:00:00.0000117 [thread 15]
[11:24:12.608579] trce: Processed 'System.Windows.Forms' in 00:00:00.0005809
[11:24:12.631565] info: Added 'System.Windows.Forms'
[11:24:12.631565] trce: Loaded System in 00:00:00.0000142 [thread 15]
[11:24:12.632564] trce: Processed 'System' in 00:00:00.0005263
[11:24:12.658549] info: Added 'System'
[11:24:12.658549] trce: Loaded System.Drawing in 00:00:00.0000142 [thread 30]
[11:24:12.658549] trce: Processed 'System.Drawing' in 00:00:00.0000622
[11:24:12.661548] info: Added 'System.Drawing'
[11:24:12.661548] trce: Loaded System.Design in 00:00:00.0000110 [thread 30]
[11:24:12.662548] trce: Processed 'System.Design' in 00:00:00.0006612
[11:24:12.678539] info: Added 'System.Design'
[11:24:12.678539] trce: Loaded System.Drawing.Design in 00:00:00.0000149 [thread 86]
[11:24:12.678539] trce: Processed 'System.Drawing.Design' in 00:00:00.0000216
[11:24:12.678539] info: Added 'System.Drawing.Design'
[11:24:16.674259] info: Shadow cache base directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_021c9b12\WinFormsDesigner
[11:24:16.700243] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Preparing shadow cache folder.
[11:24:16.702242] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: NetCoreServerLayout - Platform: AnyCPU, Normalized PlatformName: x64
[11:24:16.706239] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Copying design tools server common files from: 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\windows.forms\DesignToolsServer\Common'.
[11:24:16.817177] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Copying design tool server platform-specific files from: 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\windows.forms\DesignToolsServer\x64'.
[11:24:16.836166] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Copying 'E:\#Projects\WinFormsApp1TEST\WinFormsApp1TEST\obj\Debug\net7.0-windows\WinFormsApp1TEST.designer.deps.json' to 'DesignToolsServer.deps.json'
[11:24:16.840164] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Copying 'E:\#Projects\WinFormsApp1TEST\WinFormsApp1TEST\obj\Debug\net7.0-windows\WinFormsApp1TEST.designer.runtimeconfig.json' to 'DesignToolsServer.runtimeconfig.json'
[11:24:16.922117] info: Shadow caching completed.
[11:24:16.946103] info: IServerConnectionTimeoutProvider: Starting execution of winFormsOptions task.
[11:24:16.949101] info: Obtained ServerConnectionTimeout value: 120000.
[11:24:16.949101] info: Obtained OutputWindowLoggingService.
[11:24:16.982083] info: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Launching design tools server process...
[11:24:21.229659] fail: [WinFormsApp1TEST]: Invalid value for dpi: 0
```

where is the problem? some friends told me to uninstall the whole VS and reinstall it again. But I'm looking for the reason which causes this issue.

Comment: @jimi it will not fix the problem, and my VS was working well 7 days ago, this problem has been new for the last 2 days. I do not know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't read the whole thing. This seems to be related to the out-of-process designer. Try to disable it in the Options of VS, restart, then enable it again. See whether it fixes it, you have different exceptions or, well, it remains the same

Comment: @Jimi could you please guide me to the related option location?

Comment: `Tools->Options->Environment->Preview Features->Use the Preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer [...]`

Comment: @Jimi the same as before :(

Comment: Did you *restart* the machine after the change? -- Is this related to the latest 17.7.5 update, i.e., the problem came out right away? Or after a Windows update? -- You can also rollback a previous version, not just reinstall VS from scratch. If this also doesn't solve the problem, you have a much deeper issue

Comment: @Jimi Yeah I restarted the whole system two times, after disabling and after re-enabling.  and the problem started without updating, my version was 17.7.4, after facing this problem I updated to 17.7.5.

Comment: Then try to repair the installation, you find the option in the VS Installer (`More->Repair`). A timeout while initiating the connection / pipeline was a pre 17.2 issue. Unless it has been caused by a not that successful Windows update. Check the dates of the updates around the time when VS started misbehaving -- Disable add-inns (e.g., a standard - MS - tool used to generate multi-language support often generates delays)

Comment: @Jimi I have updated the question with some new information, could you please give it a look?

Comment: Did you change a value in the Registry to make VS start as a Dpi-Unaware process? If so, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and remove the line

Comment: @Jimi no there is not such a key in the registry, I also uninstalled the whole VS from my system, cleaned the registry, and so on, then reinstalled the VS version 17.7.5 the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you have `/noScale` in the shortcut that launches VS? Did you do / change anything related to Dpi scaling? Do all .NET 5+ apps fail with the same exception, or just the one? Did you try with a new, blank, app? If it's just one app, has it been updated from .NET Framework? --  Can you post the Project's file?

Comment: @Jimi I had checked all of these and I'm aware of all. I tried several blank WinForms app but no success. I installed the 17.4.3 version and now it is working well. It seems the problem will appear from 17.5.x versions. and I do not know why

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific VS issue that causes this exception. Of course I have tested all version of VS, to the current 17.5.5, and this has never happened. I know of a couple of similar problems, caused (IIRC) by an old add-in, a faulty Shell extension and, as mentioned, by someone tampering with the DPI awareness of VS -- If you have the chance, test a new VS installation in a clean machine

Comment: Same problem here, VS 17.9.3, .NET 8, WinForms, none of our forms can be opened anymore. None of the above mentioned helped. "Windows Forms Output": Failed to launch design tools server process process, System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple instances of 'ICollectionEditorFactory' exported with the name 'SeriesCollectionEditor'.